# how to render single content object in typo3 programmatically

Tags: typo3-9.x

I would like to render a single content object in Typo3 using a custom view helper.

The background is the adaptation of my view helper for version 9 of Typo3.

Unfortunately I can't get any further with this.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace XXX\XXX\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class ContentViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    /**
     * Parse content element and return HTML
     *
     *
     * @param    int           UID des Content Element
     * @return   string        Geparstes Content Element
     */

    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('uid', 'int', 'the unique id of the content element', true, NULL);
    }

    public function render()
    {

        $conf = array(
            'tables' => 'tt_content',
            'dontCheckPid' => 1,
            'uid' => $this->arguments['uid']
        );

        #At this point I can not find out how to solve the problem


        return $this->render(TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\AbstractContentObject::class, $conf);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [this VHS viewhelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Content/RenderViewHelper.html)?

If you really needs to implements your own viewhelper, you can easily take your inspiration from there: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/4f5bb48afcdc109738a67c8b8fa7de7b66368a7e/Classes/ViewHelpers/Content/RenderViewHelper.php#L43